# Selenium Java. Navigating WebElement by linkText issue

Tags: java, selenium

I am running a Selenium test. I have link that I need to click. I have done many links, but this one does not allow me to click it...However, it works perfectly fine when I do it manually!
Here is its html of the link element:

```
 <a href="form_general_power.asp" onclick="resetSearch();" target="mainFrame">Advanced Search</a>
```

I tried each of the following

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a [@href='form_general_power.asp']"));
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a [@onclick='resetSearch();']"));
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a [@target='mainFrame']"));
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Advanced Search"));

element.click();
```

Is there any other method of dealing with a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=\"Advanced Search\"]"));
element.click();
```

Note that there are no spaces in the xpath like you have in your examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using the css selector.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("/..."));
```

The problem with the linkText is that is is sometimes is not responsive
element.click();